# PresentModalViewController removes subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

This is driving me crazy! I have a UIViewController with 1 button.

The VC loads and I place a view into the VC:

```
[self.view addSubview:myView]
```

When you press the button, it presents a Modal:

```
    [self presentModalViewController:self.newVC animated:YES];
```

When that modal appears, it removes the subview I have added. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: first of all: `self.newVC` i would not have a UIViewController as a member of another one. 

more importantly: how are you dismissing the modalviewcontroller?

Comment: The custom VC (PDF READER) has a delegate method that is calls the class that presented it. In that method, I call:
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: you need to dismiss the modalviewcontroller from the first viewcontroller not from itself.
so in the VC class you should call `[[self presentingViewController]dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: It is being called from the first VC. VC1 presents VC2. VC1 is the delegate for VC2. VC2 has a delegate method that triggers the dismiss in VC1. This is definitely not the issue. When the modal is animating onto the screen, you see the subview removed.

Comment: ok - im sorry i misunderstood your first answer to my comment =)
how did you add the subviews in the first place? did you create your view with code or IB?
please provide additional information in your question with code.

Answer (score 0):

When you present the modal view controller its view pops up and covers the existing view until you dismiss the modal view controller.

Until you do this the original view (and your button) will remain hidden behind it.

Comment: The subview is not hidden, it is removed. When I dismiss the modal, they are no longer on the screen. I think this has just started happening with the update to 5.1. You can actually seethe subview go away as the modal animates onto the screen.

Comment: Thank you for your time. It was an error on my part. I had viewWillDisappear in my VC that removed the view. That is called whenever a modal window is presented.